# Don't know what I'm doing wrong because my toString() isn't outputting anything

Tags: java, stdout

I don't know why my `toString()` isn't working. I tried to search and find out, but I couldn't find anything. When I run the program, its just blank and doesn't output anything.

Here is my driver class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Telephone t1 = new Telephone(555,666,777, "mario");

    t1.toString();
}
```

Telephone Class with omitted getter and setter methods.

```
public class Telephone {

    int areaCode, threeDigit, fourDigit;
    String userName;

    public Telephone(int areaCode, int threeDigit, int fourDigit, String userName) { 
        this.areaCode = areaCode;          
        this.threeDigit = threeDigit;       //constructor
        this.fourDigit = fourDigit;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public Telephone() {
        this.areaCode = 555;
        this.threeDigit = 555;            //default constructor
        this.fourDigit = 555;
        this.userName = null;
    }

    public Telephone(Telephone other) {
        areaCode = other.areaCode;
        threeDigit = other.threeDigit;           //copy constructor
        fourDigit = other.fourDigit;
        userName = other.userName;
    }


    public boolean equals(Telephone obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        } else if (!(obj instanceof Telephone)) {
            return false;
        } else
            return false;
    }

    public String toString(){

        String result = "The phone number of " + userName + "is: " + areaCode + 
        "-" + threeDigit + "-" + fourDigit;

        return result;
    }

}
```

I have a requirement where I'm supposed to use the toString() to output the statement. If I didn't have that requirement, then I would know what to do, but I don't know in this case.

Comment: The statement `t1.toString()` should show an error message like `toString() is not defined for Telephone`.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `toString` doesn't write anything to standard output (stdout). For that, you can call `System.out.println(String)`.like

```
System.out.println(t1.toString());
```

Comment: Right, I know how to do that. But I have a requirement where I need to make a toString() method that will return the userName and phone number of the person.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `toString()` doesn't cause standard output. If you wish that it do so, change your `toString()` function to:

```
public String toString(){

    String result = "The phone number of " + userName + "is: " + areaCode + 
    "-" + threeDigit + "-" + fourDigit;

    System.out.println(result); // Added line to print result
    return result;
}
```

If instead, you want it to return the string and then print it in `main()`, try changing `main()` to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Telephone t1 = new Telephone(555,666,777, "mario");

    System.out.println(t1.toString()); // Added line to print result
}
```

Comment: Printing inside of toString is non-standard and very discouraged. The purpose of toString is to return a meaningful string of the object instead of something gibberish so a print method would print whatever the toString is returning

Comment: I have a requirement where I need to make a toString() method that will return the userName and phone number of the person.

Comment: @J.Doe I would use the second method then.